# Most efficent use for executor and futures to minimize initialization costs

Tags: java, performance, threadpool, future, executorservice

This question is as much theoretical to learn as it is of practical relevance to my code, but I'm curious what goes on under the hood.

I have a very simple object I create which will generate one or two futures, but probably never more then two per initialization. If you're curious the futures are for DB calls and the object is little more then a helper function to avoid redundant code. I will likely use it in a part of my code that will be run in a loop thousands of times at least, and speed is important. I'm wondering what the best way of building the futures is, from an efficiency standpoint. Would any of these options be noticeably faster or preferable?

1. building the futures by hand, without an executor service
2. initiating an executor service for so few futures (what is the expense of initializing an executor vs. gain when creating futures?)
3. passing in a pre-initialized executor service

I don't know what the executor is doing behind the scenes. I assume there is thread pooling and other overhead being eliminated by an executor service such that passing in a pre-initialized `ExecutorService` would get me a (small) speed gain? However, if anyone can quantify what expenses may be entailed in each option, and what gain I may see by preferring one over the other that would satisfy my curiosity. I'm not looking for full benchmarking, just a general understanding of tradeoffs being made which may help to inform me enough that I can have an idea which approach should be my *first* attempt at efficiency, prior to benchmarking and optimization, or alternatively if there is minimal expense for any option above that's a fine answer as well.

Any interesting details which will make me more knowledgeable about futures and executors and efficient utilization of them is welcome actually; this question is as much about learning as about my current code. (I suspect that i will see minimal speed increase in my current code; it's just what inspired the curiosity.)

Comment: How do you intend to create the `Future`s by hand? Are you spawning asynchronous tasks? Does your database access library operate asynchronously?

Comment: I get the feeling there may be a fundamental misunderstanding. In order to create any future you _must_ have an ExecutionContext available. ExecutionContexts can be implemented many ways, and creating one from an executor is common. So I am curious what you mean by "building the futures by hand, without an executor service". Do you mean using **scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global** as your EC? For the record, I think the default for global is a ThreadPool Executor that has one Thread per core of your processor.